# Adding symbols and annotations to Highchart date axis

Tags: highcharts

I need to add graphic annotations in a chart on the date (x) axis, so I added a new series with a constant value of 0 (x: date, y: 0), with custom image markers. Annotations look like this:

[image]

The problem with this approach is that the constant 0 value in the annotation series is messing around with the automatically placed ticks (on the right), which then stretch the whole Y range from 0 onwards, instead of the min and max of other series, as it is by default. That drastically affects the display of other series, whose value are far away from 0, making them look less diverse.

Highcharts comes with an annotation module, bit I didn't find an option to pin it to the axis and use a different graphic.

Is it possible to either:
a) Prevent the annotation series to influence the Y axis ticks?
b) Make customized annotations on the X axis without adding new constant series?

Comment: a) Yes, you create a separate yAxis for the constant series, that way it will not influence the yAxis of the real series. b) You can create a annotations based on the minimum yAxis value or step by step for the yAxis value at that step. All viable options, all dependent on how you get your data, if it will change (much), and if you plan to display more data in the same chart. The easier would probably be to use your constant series with a new yAxis, but also the least flexible.

Comment: @ewolden I think a new axis is exactly what I need. Can you please make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution here I think would be to create a new yAxis, and have your constant series use that yAxis. Like this:

```
yAxis: [{
  ...//original yAxis
}, {
  visible: false //this hides all axis lines, ticks, and labels
}]
```

Then in the series, you would set:

```
series: [{
  ...   //Real data series
}, {
  yAxis: 1, //constant series
  ...  
}]
```